# Find all the documents having * in them in MongoDB

Tags: json, regex, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Can someone please help me with the regex for * in MongoDB.
I want to fetch all the documents having '*' in them.

like that regex (db.collection.find{value: new Regex('*')}) should return all such documents

```
{"id":1,value:"abc/123/*"}
{"id":2,value:"abc/*/lmn"}
{"id":3,value:"abc*lmn"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close; you just need to add a backslash to escape the `*` in your regex so it won't be treated as a special character.

In the shell:

```
db.collection.find({value: /\*/})
```